# Chebyshev equation for shifted Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials, chebyshev-polynomials

The Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind ${\displaystyle T_{n}}(x)$ are given by the solutions of the following equation:
$${\displaystyle (1-x^{2})y''-xy'+n^{2}y=0,} \quad \quad (1)$$
i.e. $y(x)=T_n(x)$. I would like to know how this equation changes if we consider $T_n\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-1\right)$ instead of $T_n(x)$. Just replace $x$ with $\frac{x^2}{2}-1$ in (1) or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It depends...**

If you consider a point $u =\frac{x^2}{2}-1$, but still study the map $x \mapsto T_n\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-1\right)$, then yes, you can replace $x$ with $u =\frac{x^2}{2}-1$ in equation $(1)$.

But if your question is related to the map $R_n(x) = T_n\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-1\right)$, then you have to take the derivatives of the compositions

$$\begin{aligned}
R_n^\prime(x)=&x T_n^\prime\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-1\right)\\
R_n^{\prime \prime}(x)=& T_n^\prime\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-1\right) + x^2 T_n^{\prime\prime}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}-1\right)
\end{aligned}$$ and use those relations in equation $(1)$.

Comment: Thank you! Then Eq. (1) becomes $(1-x^{2})\left(R_n''(x)-R_n'(x)/x\right)/x^2-R_n'(x)+n^{2}y=0$?